# Reading a text file using nested for loop in python

Tags: python-2.7

i have a file

```
section2
Number of configurations:2
Configuration1
Number Of Pw:1
PW1
Frame_Type: E1 Unframed
Line_Code: AMI
Psn_Type:UDP/IPv4
Pw_Type: SAToP
Oam_Status: Enable
Prevent_PW_Broadcast: Enable
Multiplexing_Mode: Source
Out_Label: 1
In_Label: 8190
Payload_Size_Bytes: 128
Jitter_Buffer_Size: 10000
VLAN Tagging:Enable
VLAN ID:100
VLAN PRIORITY:1
file_name: MITOPExTx.img
server_ip: 192.168.205.23
software_version: 4.0(0.5)
EndPW
EndConfiguration
Configuration2
PW1
Frame_Type: E1 Unframed
Line_Code: AMI
Psn_Type: MEF
Pw_Type: SAToP
Oam_Status: Disable
Prevent_PW_Broadcast: Disable
Multiplexing_Mode: Destination
Out_Label: 16
In_Label: 1
Payload_Size_Bytes: 40
Jitter_Buffer_Size: 20000
EndPW
EndConfiguration
```

From this file first i need to read configuration 1,then under that i need to reed Pw1 and then under that i need to read the configurations.at time i should read until Endconfiguration.

After doing the configurations i need to read the configuration 2 and pw under that.Can someone help me with this

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please mention your code or possible solution you thought of. Go to docs.python.org and see how to read a file in python if you are new at this.

Comment: Have you attempted this yourself? At the moment, this reads as *"Please write my code for me"*

Comment: for pw_num in range(int(testcase_dict['Number Of Pw'])): #####configure all the pw
  Num_PW = int(pw_num) + 1  
  test_file =  open("Section%sConfigurations.txt" %qvs_section, 'r')
  test_lines = test_file.readlines()  
  exit
  PW = "PW" + str(Num_PW) 
  EndPW = "EndPW" 
  Temp = False
  for i in test_lines:   
   if Testcase == i.strip():     
    for i in test_lines:         
     if PW == i.strip():            
      for i in test_lines:
       print i             
              if i == EndPW:
        break
    if i == "EndConfiguration":
      break

Comment: i think that in the three for loops the test file is being read from the starting in contradict toc

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need nested for loops:

```
test_file = open("Section{}Configurations.txt".format(qvs_section))
read_test_file = test_file.readlines()
count = 1
for line in read_test_file:
    if line.strip() == "PW1":
        print "Config{} Started".format(count)
        continue
    if line.strip() == "EndPW":
        print "Config{} Finished".format(count)
        count += 1
        continue
    print line.strip()
```

OR using re

```
import re
config_file=open("Section{}Configurations.txt".format(qvs_section))
config_file_string=config_file.read()
number_of_configs = int((re.findall("Number of configurations:(.*?)\n", config_file_string))[0].strip())
for i in range(number_of_configs):
    print "CONFIGURATION:{}".format(i+1)
    re_pattern="Configuration{}(.*?)EndConfiguration".format(i+1)
    config = re.findall(re_pattern, config_file_string, re.DOTALL)
    for line in config[0].split("\n"):
        print "\t{}".format(line.strip())
```